# Why Div elements not show in one line?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I show the div elements in one line

I tried solutions in the site but still not working

This is the view code :

```
<div class="row">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="col-md-4 thumbnail" style="margin-left:30px;margin-bottom:30px; height:100px;border:solid;float:left;width:350px;">
            <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)</h3>
            <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)</h3>
            @Html.ActionLink(" Show Result ", " Results ", new { sId = Model.FirstOrDefault().id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" });
        
    </div>
}
</div>
```

See the image view I need the output to be in one line inside the box

1  Sample No 1   Show Result

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="col-md-4 thumbnail" style="margin-left:30px;margin-bottom:30px; height:100px;border:solid;float:left;width:350px;">
        <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)</h3>
            @Html.ActionLink("Show Result", "Results", new { sId = Model.FirstOrDefault().id }, new { @class "btn btn-primary" });
    </div>
}
```

or change H3 heading to H4